# CommitEdit function gets executed on creation of the table

Tags: javafx, edit, tablecell

I have a custom editable table cell for my table view. Now, the issue I have is that the `commitEdit()` function gets executed when the table is created. The issue is that it slows down the program as I'm updating items in my database and every single item gets updated.

```
public class ChoiceBoxCell extends TableCell<Student, Classroom> {

    ChoiceBox<Classroom> classroomChoiceBox;

    public ChoiceBoxCell(ObservableList<Classroom> classroomObservableList) {
        classroomChoiceBox = new ChoiceBox<>();
        classroomChoiceBox.setItems(classroomObservableList);

        classroomChoiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue != null) {
                processEdit(newValue);
            }
        });
    }
    private void processEdit(Classroom value) {
        commitEdit(value);
        classroomChoiceBox.setValue(value);
        setGraphic(classroomChoiceBox);
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setGraphic(classroomChoiceBox);
    }

    @Override
    public void commitEdit(Classroom value) { // gets executed on start up
        super.commitEdit(value);
        Student student = (Student) getTableRow().getItem();
        student.setClassroom(value);
        new StudentDao().updateStudent(student); // students get updated for no reason
        classroomChoiceBox.setValue(value);
        setGraphic(classroomChoiceBox);
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();
        Classroom value = getItem();
        if (value != null) {
            classroomChoiceBox.setValue(value);
            setGraphic(classroomChoiceBox);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Classroom item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (item == null || empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            classroomChoiceBox.setValue(item);
            setGraphic(classroomChoiceBox);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Solution - thanks to @James_D

```
classroomChoiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue != null && newValue != getItem()) {
            processEdit(newValue);
        }
    });
```

Comment: ANY change of the choicebox value will cause a communication with the database, even if it's caused by the `updateItem` method...

Comment: Hm, that's a bummer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am just not understanding this question. Why don't you just put an extra condition in the `if` statement so you don't call `processEdit` if nothing has changed?

Comment: @James_D I tried to add `if (newValue != null && newValue != oldValue)` to the `if` statement, but it still get's executed. I also tried setting a `boolean` var in the `ChoiceBoxCell` and only allow to update items when it's `true` (which I'd set after my `TableView` was created), but it didn't help.

Comment: `newItem` will never be equal to `oldItem`, else it wouldn't trigger a change. You need to compare it to the cell's item.

Comment: Ohh, now it works. I have to say, big thank you once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution - thanks to James_D

```
classroomChoiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue != null && newValue != getItem()) {
            processEdit(newValue);
        }
    });
```